# Weka: How do I get the prediction value in java for a test instance?

Tags: java, weka, bayesian

I have successfully trained a classifier (bayesnet) and constructed a test set (ARFF-format), which has one instance, with one missing value.

```
Evaluation eTest = new Evaluation(trainingInstance);
eTest.evaluateModel(bayes_Classifier, testInstance);
```

How can I access the prediction for the missing value? I have tested both ARFF structures (training & Test) with the GUI. They work. I simply do not know, how to access the prediction value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `eTest.evaluateModelOnce()` which would return a double value, the prediction for a single `testInstance`.  The `evaluateModel()` method is intended for multiple instances.