# Test a single instance in Weka

Tags: java, weka

Does weka require the test instances to have the class attribute.
I have used a training set arff file to train the classifier. Now I want to test an instance (not from arff file, have to create by code) without the class attribute and predict the class.
I found this link [Weka: How do I get the prediction value in java for a test instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8957926/1138148)

But my class attribute is a string 'Y' or 'N'. If evaluateModelOnce() returns double, what does it mean. Is it the class attribute or something else. i am using the weka API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test instances, the instances must have class labels. Even if you provide class labels, when classifying with the built model, Weka does not see the test instance's class labels. Rather after the testing, it matches whether or not its prediction about the test instance's class is correct. If you have labels in training instances (which you must have) and not on the test instances, then you will get an error message something like "the training and testing sets are not compatible." Thank you.

Comment: Ok I got the point. You need to provide class labels in order to find the accuracy of prediction. But after testing if I need to predict the class value (I don't have the class value), what should I do ?

Comment: So, you want Weka's labeling on your test instances based on the learned model?

Comment: If you don't know the actual class values for test instances, keep class feature in your test dataset but put "?" mark to all the class feature values.

Comment: @Rushdi. So basically what you're saying is that when a training set looks like this [1,2,3,4,Class] the test set for a trained model would look like so [2,1,3,1,?] If that's true, where should we look for the class that was assigned to this instance in place of [?] ?

Comment: @Rushdi : Yes I need the class labeling based on the model.

Comment: @pguzewicz : Exactly what I wanted to ask.

Comment: I am sorry as I was away for a long time. You can check "Show prediction" options on the classification tab to see the labeling of the test instances with the help of a training model. The labels will be shown on the result pane.