# Test single instance in weka which has no class label

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, prediction

This question is being already asked but i didn't understand the answer so I am again posting the question please do reply.

I have a weka model eg: j48 I have trained that model for my dataset and now I have to test the model with a single instance in which it should return the class label. How to do it?

I have tried these ways:

1)When I am giving my test instance a,b,c,class for class as ?. It is showing problem evaluating classifier .train and test are not compatible

2)When I list all the class labels and I put the ? for the class label for the test instance like this:

```
@attribute class {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27}

@data
1,2,............,?
```

It is not showing any results like this

```
=== Evaluation on test set ===
=== Summary ===

Total Number of Instances                0     
Ignored Class Unknown Instances                  1     

=== Detailed Accuracy By Class ===

               TP Rate   FP Rate   Precision   Recall  F-Measure  ROC Area  Class
                 0         0          0         0         0         ?        1
                 0         0          0         0         0         ?        2
                 0         0          0         0         0         ?        3
Weighted Avg.  NaN       NaN        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

confusion matrix is null

What to do?

Comment: Please give us a link to the other question you're mentioning. Also, I don't understand what you are doing in 1) and 2). Can you give use the command you're executing? And please try better formatting.

Comment: the link is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649708/test-a-single-instance-in-weka/10657512#10657512

Comment: the test instance given is: 1,2,3,class label for the class label i gave ? .Therefore the test instance:1,2,3,?

Comment: You still didn't give the command line which led to this output. I think I know what your problem is, but please tell us to be sure.

Comment: sorry for the late reply i did't give any commands i just choose the j48 classifier and pass the training and test data to the training set and supplied single instance to the supplied test set and got the above results

Comment: No, you don't understand me: How did you run it? Command line? GUI? From Java? You're way too unspecific. How did you train the model? How did you supply the instance?

Comment: It is from gui weka explorer

Comment: Man, you're killing me. If you really want people to help you, you really shouldn't let us have to worm everything out of you. I'll try to answer now.

Comment: sir i have clearly mentioned may be i didn't clearly present you.I am sorry for the inconvience created for you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the incomplete information from the OP, here is what probably happened:

You used

1. the **Weka GUI Chooser**
2. selected the **Weka Explorer**
3. loaded your training data on the **Preprocess** tab
4. selected the **Classify** tab
5. selected the **J48** classifier
6. selected **Supplied test set** under test options and supplied your aforementioned test set
7. clicked on **Start**

Now to you problem:

"*Evaluation on test set*" should have given it away, because you're are evaluating the classifier -or better: the trained model. But for evaluation, you need to compare the predicted class with the **actual** class, which you didn't supply. Hence, the instance with the missing class label will be ignored.

Since you don't have any other test instances WITH class label, the confusion matrix is empty. There simply is not enough information available to build one. (And just as a side note: A confusion matrix for only one instance is kinda worthless.)

### To see the actual prediction

You have to go to **More options ...**, click on **Choose** next to **Output predictions** and select an output format, e.g. **PlainText**, and you will see something like:

```
inst#     actual  predicted error prediction
    1        1:?        1:0       0.757 
    2        1:?        1:0       0.824 
    3        1:?        1:0       0.807 
    4        1:?        1:0       0.807 
    5        1:?        1:0       0.79 
    6        1:?        2:1       0.661
```

This output lists the classified instances in the order they occur in the test file. This example was taken from [the Weka site about "Making predictions"](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions) with the following explanation.

> In this case, taken directly from a test dataset where all class
>   attributes were marked by "?", the "actual" column, which can be
>   ignored, simply states that each class belongs to an unknown class.
>   The "predicted" column shows that instances 1 through 5 are predicted
>   to be of class 1, whose value is 0, and instance 6 is predicted to be
>   of class 2, whose value is 1. The error field is empty; if predictions
>   were being performed on a labeled test set, each instance where the
>   prediction failed to match the label would contain a "+". The
>   probability that instance 1 actually belongs to class 0 is estimated
>   at 0.757.

Comment: sir can you please explain the output

Comment: i understood the output

Comment: Okay, but to be sure I've added some explanation and linked to the Weka website

Comment: Is it possible to also do this in java?

Comment: Weka is pure Java, so yes. You can look up the source code and see what is executed with the given arguments, so you should be able to include this in your own program, if that is what you're asking.