# How do I test a single Instance in Weka using a model that I have built?

Tags: java, api, machine-learning, weka, j48

I am trying to test a single instance using weka API in Java. My aim is to predict the class value of the single instance in the test.arff file.

My java code looks like this,

```
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.trees.J48;
import weka.classifiers.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class WekaNew {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Weka Tool");

        BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("train.arff"));
        Instances train = new Instances(breader);
        train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() -1);
        breader.close();    //loading training data

        BufferedReader treader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.arff"));
        Instances test = new Instances(treader);
        test.setClassIndex(test.numAttributes() -1);
        treader.close();        //loading testing data

        Classifier cls = new J48();
        cls.buildClassifier(train);

        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
        eval.evaluateModelOnce(cls,test);

        System.out.println(eval.toMatrixString("\nConfusion Matrix\n========\n"));

    }

}
```

The train.arff has 7(attributes)+1(class label) along with 132 instances of data.
The test.arff has 7 attributes + 1 class label=? with ONE instance.

I want to predict the class label of the single instance in the test.arff.
How do I go about predicting the label and what changes are needed to be made in the dataset and the code?

I tried compiling the java file by "javac -cp "/classpath" WekaNew.java"
, it gives the following error "No suitable method found for evaluateModelOnce()"

**New to the Weka API and Java in general. Apologies in advance if the question seems repeated.**

I have also referred the following questions in Stackoverflow,
1. [Test single instance in weka which has no class label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18216266/test-single-instance-in-weka-which-has-no-class-label)
2. [Test a single instance in Weka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649708/test-a-single-instance-in-weka)
but it does not seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the signature of evaluateModelOnce:

```
public double evaluateModelOnce(Classifier classifier,
                                Instance instance)
```

(see http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html#evaluateModelOnce-weka.classifiers.Classifier-weka.core.Instance-)

However, you pass in "Instances" instead of "Instance", which are different classes. Thus, this is a syntax error.

To evaluate a single Weka Instance, you might want to try

```
    eval.evaluateModelOnce(cls,instances.firstInstance());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm! Is there any way I could identify the class label of the test instance?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to do? You already know that the class label is at `test.numAttributes() -1`, right?